# Chromecast Receiver Chrome Application

Tags: chromecast

I'm experimenting with Chromecast receiver application on Chrome.
Here are steps I've taken:

1. I registered for Chrome Case Developer Console (Paid $5)
2. I created a Custom Receiver application
3. I have two chromecast devices, I've added both serial numbers to my console under Devices tab and both are showing as Ready For Testing
4. I've used my chromecast setup application to check mark the option for both devices to send the serial numbers to google on updates and rebooted my devices several times and waited over night! (documentation says wait 15 minutes!).
5. For Custom Receiver application I've used the code from https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideoLooping-receiver loop receiver example and copied the index.html to my webserver and tested it's available by pointing my browser to the address I entered in URL field in the application setting.
6. I have a simple sender application that sends a video to chromecast, it's working fine when I use the default receiver application Id in my code as follow:

   ```
   var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID);
   ```

   and my chromecase devices are shown, I pick one and video plays perfectly fine.
7. When I change the code to use my custom receiver's ID as follow:

   ```
   var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest("XXXXXXXX");
   ```

   Where XXXXXXXX is my application ID as I see it in the chrome case developer console my application stops working!  On InitialCastApi my receiverListener receives an "unavailable" error all the time.

I've tried this with two chromecast devices I have and two application IDs and on both I have the same issue.

My development environment is on MacOS, I have no firewall and I've tried reading documentations and stack posting as much as I can and I'm stuck.

Comment: Double check your serial number. It is easy to get wrong. The serial number should be on the Chromecast box or you can take a photo of the number printed on the device to make it more clear.

Comment: I did double check several times, serial numbers are correct for sure.

Comment: Send your serial number to us so we can debug the issue: https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?rd=1

Comment: Any news of what happened here? I'm running into a similar issue.